# Why separate routes and controllers in MVC backend applications?

Tags: mvc, ruby-on-rails

I've dabbled in a few MVC frameworks (like Rails and its ilk) and I've noticed that the file that defines restful routes often go separate from controllers which hold the actions executed through those routes.

For example, let's say that there is a route

```
/users
```

That go to UserController.create action.

I would expect it to be defined as part of the controller but it is often defined in some

```
config/routes.rb|js file
```

Why is this?

Comment: You may have more than one routes that end up to the same controller.

Comment: Note that this isn't universal. E.g. Spring MVC, which defines routes using annotations on controller methods.